# XSD definition for an XML tag with attribute and content

Tags: xml, xsd

I have written an XSD and an XML. In my XML I want to have a tag like this

```
<main name="">My text</main>
```

In my xsd I tried this

```
<xs:element name="main" type="xs:string">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:attribute name="name" use="required" />
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

This did not work. Can anybody tell me what is the correct way to define this in the XSD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use simpleContent and extend it  (defining the content as type string) like so to add the attribute:

```
  <xs:element name="main">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:simpleContent>
        <xs:extension base="xs:string">
          <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" use="required"/> 
        </xs:extension>
      </xs:simpleContent>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
```